# Any way to create a JWT token with key size 512? and changing default minimum size requirement of AsymmetricSignatureProvider

Tags: jwt, token, rsa, .net-core-3.1

I am currently getting following error:

> IDX10630: The 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: '...', InternalId: '5a946596-9fe6-4c91-8c52-9b140849c7a4'.' for signing cannot be smaller than '2048' bits. KeySize: '512'

I use the following method:

```
 public string GetIdTokenString(Dictionary<string, string> inputClaims, string privateKey)
        {
            string result = null;
            try
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();                
                privateKey = privateKey.Replace("-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", String.Empty).Replace("-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----", String.Empty);
                var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
                byte[] privateKeyPasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mypassword);
                List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
                foreach (var o in inputClaims)
                {                    
                    claims.Add(new Claim(o.Key, o.Value));
                }
                int length = 0;
                RSA rSA = RSA.Create();
                rSA.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyPasswordBytes, privateKeyBytes, out length);
                RsaSecurityKey securitykey = new RsaSecurityKey(rSA)
                {
                    KeyId = "......"
                };
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60 * 5),
                    Audience = ...,
                    Issuer = .....                   

                };
                tokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securitykey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);


                if (token != null && token is JwtSecurityToken)
                {
                    result = (token as JwtSecurityToken).RawData;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Fatal(ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

there is a code mentioned in post

[Error Creating JWT Token using RSA Security Key with key size less than 2048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117838/error-creating-jwt-token-using-rsa-security-key-with-key-size-less-than-2048)

but I'm not able to run it in .net core 3.1

One more thing is about over riding value in
AsymmetricSignatureProvider.DefaultMinimumAsymmetricKeySizeInBitsForSigningMap

Any way i can change value of particular Key?

One thing i have tried which didn't work is

```
 var mainclass = typeof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider)
                .GetField(nameof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider.DefaultMinimumAsymmetricKeySizeInBitsForSigningMap), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
                var field = mainclass.GetValue(null) as Dictionary<string, int>;
                if (field != null)
                {
                    field["RS256"] = 512;
                }

                var mainclass2 = typeof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider).GetField(nameof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider.DefaultMinimumAsymmetricKeySizeInBitsForVerifyingMap), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                var field2 = mainclass2.GetValue(null) as Dictionary<string, int>;
                if (field2 != null)
                {
                    field2["RS256"] = 512;
                }
```

Comment: Now why do you suppose they won't accept a keysize less than 2048?

Comment: they?
I am supporting a legacy application where key generation is responsibility of old component which currently generate key of size 512.
I have to utilize that key for generating and validating id token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the solution i have used

```
var mainclass = typeof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider)
                       .GetField(nameof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider.DefaultMinimumAsymmetricKeySizeInBitsForSigningMap), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                var field = mainclass.GetValue(null) as Dictionary<string, int>;
                if (field != null)
                {
                    field["RS256"] = 512;

                }

                var mainclass2 = typeof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider).GetField(nameof(AsymmetricSignatureProvider.DefaultMinimumAsymmetricKeySizeInBitsForVerifyingMap), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                var field2 = mainclass2.GetValue(null) as Dictionary<string, int>;
                if (field2 != null)
                {
                    field2["RS256"] = 512;
                }
```