# Any possibility of creating ClaimsIdentity directly from serialized string or Claim From serilize string with json array type

Tags: c#, jwt, claims, .net-core-3.1

I have a list of claims in my object Dictionary inputClaims from which i am creating claim.
One claim type is array but it is always initialized as string.
Any idea how can i create Claim with Array type

Comment: You'll need to serialize and deserialize the array into/from JSON string if you want to store it inside a claim...

Comment: can you please provide related code ?

Comment: JsonClaimValueTypes.Json did the trick. Related code is at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599339/any-way-to-create-a-jwt-token-with-key-size-512-and-changing-default-minimum-si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have found out that I have to use JsonClaimValueTypes.JsonArray

My Claim initialization looks like following

```
new Claim("amr", JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<string> { "SIM_PIN" }), JsonClaimValueTypes.JsonArray)
```